# Why was shar written if tar already existed?

Tags: tar, history, bsd

According to the BSD man pages, tar first appeared in Version 7 UNIX in 1979, but shar first appeared in 4.4BSD, which was released in 1994.

What were the perceived advantages to shar at the time? Shar introduces a host of security issues since it's just executing a lengthy shell script. Why would this tool be introduced when tar already provided similar functionality?

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1168/

Comment: My conjecture would be that `tar` requires, well, `tar`, and, at that point, probably `uudecode` since tar archives are not 7-bit clean, whereas `shar` only requires `sh`.

Comment: Before shar there were other tools for creating shell archives, I definitely used those archives before 1990

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the source (and weight you may attach), `shar` dates back to around 1980.  In a form which you might recognize, that comes from Rich Salz's implementation introduced in 1988, and improved in stages over the next few years.

`shar` was originally a convenience for bundling text files.  uuencoding (a way to send binary files) has been around at least as long: I see it in 2.0BSD, dated 1989 with the manual page saying it was written by Mark Horton.  It was
in use with `shar` in the 1980s, though the earliest use in combination with `shar` is elusive. The `README` in Rich Salz's 1988 version of `cshar` states:

```
On a philosophical note, I've tried to make this all as general as
possible for shipping sources around.  I'm not interested in binaries, so
things like automatically running uuencode don't interest me a great
deal.  I haven't come up with a good portable way to split files into
pieces if they're too large, and doubt I ever will.  There are too many 
installation parameters, but I'm not particularly worried about that:  Once
you get things working, consider it incentive to avoid future changes.  
It would be nice if I could use Larry's meta-Config, but that only works 
on Unix (and Eunice).  Send me your config.h file so that others can benefit.
```

However, William Davidsen's concurrent (a month earlier) `shar2` in *comp.sources.misc* (Volume 3, Issue 14) supported uuencode.

Further reading:

- [Comments on Shar/Utils](http://invisible-island.net/personal/sharutils.html)
- [Encoding Header Field for Internet Messages](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1154.html) (RFC-1154, 1990)
- [[mailhist-discuss] Segments of email history](http://emailhistory.org/pipermail/mailhist-discuss/2012-April/000020.html) mentions Mark Horton's uuencode/uudecode
- [v02i020: secure uuencode and uudecode](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sources.amiga/XOaDhKPMJi4) (9/8/1987, mentions uudecode and shar)
- [The Technical Development of Internet Email](https://web.archive.org/web/20150303052701/https://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/an/2008/02/man2008020003.html) gives more about uuencode/uudecode, but does not mention shar.  It says that Horton wrote the programs in 1979.

Answer (score 3):

You are mistaken, shell archivers did exist no later than 1980.

They have been written for the usenet source archives in order to allow the archives to appear inside a mail. Tar is binary and cannot easily be in a usenet source archive.